# Lenovo ThinkPad T440p + Ubuntu 12.04/14.04

Tags: nvidia, 14.04, thinkpad

Is there anybody, who is able to install Ubuntu 12.04 or 14.04 (64bit) on Lenovo Thinkpad T440p and get fully functional NVIDIA Optimus? This laptop model is certified by Canonical to be fully supported by Ubuntu, but install Ubuntu 14.04 is nearly impossible, due to the fact, that 14.04 desktop ISO image crash during initial boot.

Any help?

See, for exmaple: [ThinkPad T440p: problems with various Ubuntu flavours](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/246834)

Add info regarding bad 12.04 support: [T440p problems with 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/441243/bumblebee-and-lenovo-os-crash-after-unsuccesful-installation)

Answer (score 2):

Downgrade BIOS from 2.22 to 1.14   resolved mine problems.

BIOS update utility :

http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/downloads/detail.page?DocID=DS037575

I've ran file 'gluj04us.exe' (1.14 BIOS) from Windows 7, then Laptop restarted 3 times (flash operations).

After 4th reboot laptop I've reinstalled Ubuntu 14.04 and every hardware stuff working properly.

Comment: What about NVIDIA optimus support, sleeping, power management, wifi, etc, etc. Everything really works???

Comment: Confirmed, everything works.

Comment: Including SSD disks??? See: http://askubuntu.com/questions/441243/bumblebee-and-lenovo-os-crash-after-unsuccesful-installation/502429#502429

Answer (score 1):

From your [link](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/246834) :

> I had the same problem with my T440p i7-4700MQ with Intel and Nvidia.
>
> I managed to finally boot off a 14.04 Live-DVD by pressing F6 and/or
>   ESC as soon as the "Press Enter" disappeared. Then I modified the boot
>   options to "nomodeset" which led me to the choice between "try ..."
>   and "install ...". I went for "try..." and once the desktop showed up
>   from where I then installed Trusty 64bit.
>
> It goes without saying that the boot options in grub are set to
>   nomodeset, but at least the notebook is working. WLAN is ok. I reach
>   speeds up to 780 MBit/s. There remain several issues though: display
>   brightness buttons are not functional, fingerprint reader is not
>   detected, and the proprietary nvidia driver is something that will
>   maybe work properly some day.

Edit: once you install using the "nomodeset", edit the file /etc/default/grub and remove the option "nomodeset". Then open "Additional Drivers" and install the nvidia driver. This allows the brightness buttons to work fine.

Did you try the nomodeset boot parameter?

And [instructions for installing Nvidia Prime](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/08/using-nvidia-graphics-drivers-with.html):

> Update: the instructions below should work under Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty
>   Tahr too.
>
> Note: the  nvidia-prime package only supports the proprietary Nvidia
>   drivers and won't work with Nouveau!
>
> If you're using Ubuntu 13.10 Saucy Salamander or 14.04 Trusty Tahr and
>   want to test the Optimus support in the Nvidia Graphics Drivers
>   319.12+, here's what you need to do:
>
> 1. Firstly, purge Bumblebee if installed:
>
> sudo apt-get purge bumblebee*
>
> Also, make sure libvdpau-va-gl1 is not enabled system-wide because it
>   causes Nvidia Settings to crash on start - if it is, either disable it
>   or simply remove the package:
>
> sudo apt-get purge libvdpau-va-gl1
>
> 1. Install the proprietary Nvidia drivers and the Nvidia Prime package:
>
> sudo apt-get install nvidia-319 nvidia-settings-319 nvidia-prime
>
> 1. Reboot the system.
>
> That's it, after a reboot, your laptop should be using the Nvidia GPU
>   to render the desktop.

Comment: Does not work at all!!!

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: see: [link](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/246834)

Comment: So you are getting the "SQUASHFS error: zlib decompression failed" error? Try your USB drive in a USB 2 port, or try a USB 3 drive in a USB 3 port, or try a USB DVD drive. In [this thread](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/T400-T500-and-newer-T-series/T540p-T440p-UltraDock-external-display-issues/td-p/1368847/page/4) people are reporting USB problems with T440 under Windows too. Have you [installed the latest BIOS?](http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/downloads/detail.page?DocID=DS037575)

Comment: Also see [this thread](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=176370), it seems that under certain combinations of BIOS settings it is possible to brick the laptop: they recommend turning off UEFI booting.

Comment: This answer helped me a lot, using the "nomodeset" was the only way to install 14.04. The only catch is that once it is installed I removed the "nomodeset" option from grub editing /etc/default/grub and installed the nvidia driver from the default "Additional Drivers" program. Now the computer works perfectly as a Certified Hardware model should. Thanks!

Comment: For me the key for the installation of of ubuntu 14.4 on Lenovo t440p also was also to activate "nomodeset" at the very beginning of the installation as described above by bain May 5th. Thank you for posting! Just as a little hint: I had to press Fn+F6 instead of just F6 to get into the BootOptions menue which is described for example [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions). So far I had not problem with the graphic card and I did not follow the Nividia related instructions

Answer (score 0):

Not the answer you need but I run 64-bit Ubuntu desktop on Lenovo Thinkpad X121e. It is a terribly slow laptop and I gave up trying to run Windows 7 on it.
Except for speed and lack of CD/DVD player I have no issues.

I started using 12.04 LTS and have upgraded to 14.04 LTS

Comment: Thanks, but your notebook is completely different story :)

Answer (score 0):

My Lenovo T440p has just arrived in my house. And this Laptop use UEFI and a secure boot to prevent some security problems. I have installed the latest Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64bit version just to assure you that the installation is possible. I don't know if you could install Ubuntu 12.04 as for me, it does not support the UEFI frame.

if you windows 8 have 4 partions like me, you could proceed the installation like me.

1 Disable in BIOS the Secure Boot. And shrink some space for Ubuntu, do not format it.

2 Make a U disk boot version of Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with the help of UltraISO for example.

3 Change the order of boot by taken first the U disk, and proceed the process of installation. if you chose the NVidia GT730M like me, maybe you should modify the first item during U disk boot:

click 'e' to edit the command line for Install Ubuntu when you run into the

Try Ubuntu ....
install Ubuntu
Windows 8 boot loader ...

and change the "quiet splash" to "nomodeset"

(do not type the quote mark). To prevent the black waiting screen . LOL. Click Ctrl + x to proceed.

4 You can enjoy the environment of Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. But, for me, there is still some problem with the shutdown option, Ubuntu can not shut down correctly due to some Wifi driver (Intel things).

Regards

Comment: What is exact type number of your T440p?

Comment: 20ANCTO1WW, If could help you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also experiencing problems with the T440p.
For what concernes the optimus bug, see
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1268669

Comment: Thanks! I am still waiting for any suitable solution or workaround, so far Ubuntu is not possible to reliable operate on T440p :(

Answer (score 0):

I've a T420 and I hope most of its configurations might be same as your T440p. I'm also having some issues to get the optimus to work and presently settled for using laptop in discrete(pure nvidia) graphics mode(enable/disable from BIOS) with nvidia's 331.38 version of the driver. For installation use nomodset as suggested above.

Hope this will get your laptop working.

Comment: T420 and T440p are very different (HW)

Answer (score 0):

I am able to install Ubuntu *12.04.4* desktop 64-bit on my Lenovo t440p (with SSD) from a USB stick without any BIOS downgrade. After a clean install, the wireless will not work immediately, but **it works after you find a ethernet cable to do apt-get update/upgrade**:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

It might worth a try if you are still finding a solution.

In addition, I can somehow install the later versions ("12.04.5" or "14.04.1") via various tricks I found online, but the system becomes extremely unstable ... Just my 2 cents.