# What is EFI v2.31 Lenovo? Where do I find it?

Tags: 14.04, lenovo, thinkpad, bios, hardware-certification

At http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/201307-13930/ the bios version it says is certified is EFI v2.31 Lenovo

But the latest UEFI version available from Lenovo's website is 2.25

How do I get the version that works?

Comment: Have you tried installing Ubuntu with your current version?

Comment: Yes, it's buggy as hell.  Won't shut down.  wifi doesn't work.  ethernet doesn't work after running updates.  The mouse randomly stops working and I have to switch to touchpad.

Comment: I tried an older version as suggested here: http://askubuntu.com/a/502065/63688 and that dealt with the shutdown and mouse problems but not the wifi or ethernet problems

Answer (score 3):

The [certification tool](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/checkbox-gui) gets this version from the following command:

```
[ -d /sys/firmware/efi ] && cat /var/log/kern.log* | grep -m 1 -o --color=never 'EFI v.*'
```

I have a T430S which also returns `EFI v2.31 by Lenovo`.

The EFI version number that you see on the  certification website (2.3.1, although that's often reported by software as 2.31) refers to the version of the [EFI specification](http://www.uefi.org/specifications) the firmware implements.

Comment: Now that I'm using 1.14 as recommended in http://askubuntu.com/questions/454268/lenovo-thinkpad-t440p-ubuntu-12-04-14-04/502065 I get the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in the certification site that we know about and will fix soon. As Sylvain said, 2.31 refers to the specification, not the version. The version we used when certifying this system was 0.21.

Comment: Is there a bug report we can follow?

Comment: From what I can tell, that bios version isn't available any more.  Have you done any testing on versions released within the past year?

Comment: muru - Unfortunately, bug reports against the certification site are private, as they may contain private info.

Comment: dspyz - Can you put any examples?